# Remove certain lines in string? Shell

Tags: shell

Lets say I have a variable containing the following string (separated by blank spaces but when echoed it looks like lines):

```
animal:whale
animal:dog
animal:2_mice
animal:cat
```

And I have another variable containing the names of the animals I want to delete from the first string separated by spaces.

Lets say `names="cat dog"`

How would I go about deleting the lines that contain cat and dog from the first string?

I've tried looking up sed and grep approaches but haven't found any info that would work so far.

I should also point out that the expression needs to match exactly, so if the second variable contained just ca instead of cat, cat should not get deleted.

Comment: Is names supposed to be comma separated or space separated?

Comment: Space. The contents of the names variable can contain names of multiple animals each separated by blank space.

Comment: What is exact value of your variable? Can you show `printf "%q\n" "$var"` output

Comment: Which shell are you using? The claim that the newline thing doesn't really matter for you implies that you might be on zsh.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I'm on Ubuntu. The animal names in the first variable are separated by blank spaces anyway but when echoed in double quotes, they appear as lines so that's why I called it removing a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "$variable" | grep -Ev ":($(echo "$names" | sed 's/ /|/g'))$"
```

Comment: `echo $variable` will discard the newlines (replacing them with spaces).

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! : )  I guess the newline thing does not really matter but the -P might be a problem as I'd prefer as much universal solution as possible.

Comment: Switched to -E for portability, and added support for exact matching everything from the : to the end of the line

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for all these catches, that's what I get for answering without unit tests.

Comment: ...much better. I'd still suggest using more quotes (`echo "$variable"`, not `echo $variable`, and likewise for the expansion of `$names`), since you don't necessarily want a whitespace-surrounded `*` in the input to be replaced with a list of files, but that's the only outstanding issue that I see at a glance.

Comment: Am I missing an obvious way to avoid needing to escape the quotes around `$names`?

Comment: ...using `$()` starts a new quoting context, so with `"$(foo "bar")"`, the first quote is matched only by the one at the very end.

Comment: Huh, did not know that about `$()`.  I guess maybe I really should stop using my trusty old backticks...

Comment: Seems to be working as intended, thanks a lot guys. Care to give a little commentary on the grep and sed parts of the code? Would be much appreciated : )

Comment: @Daeto, you can just run those parts individually and see what they do easily enough. `echo "$names" | sed 's/ /$|/g'`, f'rinstance.

Comment: The sed command replaces all spaces with "|$".  The grep part in turn selects all lines _not_ matching the given regular expression, so in this case not matching a colon, followed by one of the things in name (the | gives alternatives and the parens group the alternatives together), followed by the end of the line (represented by $)).  And while I'm at it, I corrected it so the colon applies to all groups

Answer (score 0):

Using grep inverse search, assumes values in names variable is space separated and one word each:

```
$ echo "$var"
animal:whale
animal:dog
animal:2_mice
animal:cat

$ echo "$names"
cat dog

$ echo "$var" | grep -v $(printf ' -e :%s$' $names)
animal:whale
animal:2_mice
```